Pasting deleted text in Powershell 7
I'm trying to add my favorite keyboard shortcuts from Linux/Bash to PowerShell to make it easier to switch between them (see code snippet below and you'll get the idea). Though there is one feature I'm not able to replicate: When deleting a word/character/line/any text in the bash terminal, you can paste the most recent text back by pressing ctrl+y. Though in PowerShell it doesn't seem like there's a feature other than pasting from the clipboard(?). A possible workaround could be making the deleted text go into the clipboard. Open for suggestions.
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord 'Alt+b' -Function BackwardWord
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord 'Alt+f' -Function ForwardWord
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord 'Ctrl+u' -Function DeleteLineToFirstChar
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord 'Ctrl+k' -Function DeleteToEnd
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord 'Ctrl+b' -Function BackwardChar
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord 'Ctrl+f' -Function ForwardChar
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord 'Ctrl+e' -Function EndOfLine
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord 'Ctrl+a' -Function BeginningOfLine

EDIT:
Almost found the solution:
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord 'Ctrl+a' -Function Yank
This pastes the previously deleted word (deleted with ctrl+w), however it doesn't seem to work for text deleted with DeleteToEnd and DeleteLineToFirstChar.
EDIT 2:
ChatGTP was able to found a solution for ctrl+k:
 Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord 'Ctrl+k' -ScriptBlock { 
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::KillLine()
}

This way the deletion is put into the kill ring and can be yanked back with ctrl+y. Though still haven't found something that works for ctrl+u.

Kill ring?
